# Read owl file using jena

Tags: java, owl, jena

I'm still learning about JENA and I want to read an OWL file using JENA inside JAVA but I'm completely lost how to read it

I don't have any code since I don't know how to actually do it

I tried to use the Model class but I got an error after importing the Model library

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Did you search for tutorials and read the docs? On GitHub `owlcs/owlapi` [Tutorial: A starter's starter](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Tutorial:-A-starter's-starter) or search SO for [`[java] owl`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20owl). Then please share your code as [example], plus any error-output.

Comment: not finding the documentation of Apache Jena? The project has a lots of tutorials and guides: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/index.html - so why can't just follow the guide and load an OWL file.

Comment: that said, not showing your current code and the error stack trace makes it rather impossible to help. Moreover, there is no "Model library", not sure what you mean. Maven is the way to go to have all Jena libraries available in your project. If you're not used to it, a small Maven guide will definitely improve your Java experience.